# Produce a round-trip string for a decimal type

Tags: c#, floating-point, type-conversion, decimal

If I wanted to convert a *double* to a *string* and back to a *double* that matches exactly, I would use something like:

```
double d1 = 1 / 3.0;
string s = d1.ToString("R");
double d2 = double.Parse(s);
```

But, the "R" format isn't defined for a *decimal* type (you get a "FormatException: Format specifier was invalid").

What is the way to produce a round-trip string for a decimal type?

Comment: The code is valid C#, and (for the given example, at least) works as intended/described. I don't know if the code there now is what @musefan saw.

Comment: @TimS.: Actually, I missed the whole `double`/`decimal` thing... my bad

Comment: The string format of a decimal already is the exact value of the decimal. **That's the point of decimal**.

Comment: @EricLippert I don't know if the change happened in the last 6y, but for me in `fi` locale `(123.123m).ToString() -> 123,123`. Have to use `(123.123m).ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) -> 123.123`. Having `$"{123.123:r}"` throw a FormatException is annoying AF.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The default output format for `decimal` round-trips, so you don't have to do anything special. It is just like `int` in that sense.

Comment: What conversion method would one have to use to produce a decimal from a string in such fashion as to ensure that "1.20" yields 1.20m rather than 1.2m?

Comment: @supercat: You would use `decimal.Parse("1.20")` to get 1.20m back -- if you use `double.Parse("1.20")` you will get 1.2d back.

Comment: I got confused because the VB.NET immediate-mode print function [which I used to test the behavior of simple .NET methods] truncates the trailing zeroes for some reason; adding `.ToString()` fixed that.

Comment: `decimal.ToString()` uses `NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo` internally, which uses the decimal separator defined on the current server. Thus, a decimal may look different when stringified e.g. on a Danish server compared to a U.S. server. Therefore, decimals are only guaranteed to "round-trip" on the same server. When using different servers, the success of the round-trip depends on the culture settings, and on the details of the decimal.Parse implementation (how tolerant it is towards unexpected decimal separator characters).

Answer (score 6):

`Decimal` is in fact a *binary-decimal value* (it uses base of **10**, not **2** as in `Double`) and that's why there's no need to special exact representations like `ToString("R")`;

```
  Decimal value = 123.456m;
  String result = value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); // <- That's enough
```

See also for details:

http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/decimal.aspx

**Edit:** Starting from **.Net 7**, you can use [INumber](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.inumber-1?view=net-7.0) interface to create a *universal* (both `decimal` and `double` and even exotic `Half`) *extension method* (see SandRock's comment below):

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.Numerics;

...

public static class MyNumberExtensions {
  public static string ToInvariantString<T>(this T value) 
    where T : INumber<T>, IFormattable {
      return value.ToString("R", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
  }
}
```

Then

```
double d = 123.45;
decimal de = 446.93m;
int i = 456;
Half h = (Half)(5.1);
                
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
  d.ToInvariantString(), 
  de.ToInvariantString(), 
  i.ToInvariantString(), 
  h.ToInvariantString()));
```

**Output:**

```
123.45
446.93
456
5.1
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gNweGf)

Comment: I created a [set of extension methods to obtain roundtrip representations of dotnet value types](https://gist.github.com/sandrock/6fe3298b8ac6d9d0d9872dd811a63908). The best way I found for `decimal` is this answer.

Comment: @SandRock: you can use `INumber<T>` (.Net 7 and higher) in your library to make it more universal, please see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

If you try,

```
decimal d1 = 1m / 3;
string s = d1.ToString();
decimal d2 = decimal.Parse(s);
// where d1 == d2 = true
```

You will see you do not need any extra formatting options to obtain a proper `string` representation.